# Higher order derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In the book I'm using (*Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin), the definition of the derivative in higher dimensions is:

> Suppose $E$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f$ maps $E$ into
>   $\mathbb{R}^m$, and $x \in E$. If there exists a linear transformation
>   $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that
>   $$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(x + h) - f(x) - Ah|}{|h|} = 0, $$
>
> then we say that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and we write
>
> $$ f'(x) = A. $$

Does this mean that polynomials of order higher than two are *not* differentiable since their derivative is non-linear? For example, if

$$ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = x^{3}, $$

then $ A := 3x^{2} $ is a function that satisfies the limit but it is *not* linear, so is $f$ *not* differentiable according to this definition since no such *linear* function exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an unfortunate terminological collision here. Rudin's "derivative" $A$ (which I'll notate $A_x: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ for a particular point $x$) is the derivative of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ *at a point* $x$. This is a linear map that takes $m$-dimensional vectors $h$ representing directions from $x$ and spits out $n$-dimensional vectors giving the "directional derivative" in the direction of $h$, scaled by the magnitude of $h$. In other words, $A_x(h)$ is defined as $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \epsilon^{-1} (f(x + \epsilon h) - f(h))$; differentiability is equivalent to the criterion that this map $A$ be defined for all $h$ and be in fact linear.

Then there's the map $x \mapsto A_x$ which gives the *general formula for the coefficients of this linear map at any point*. This map does not have to be linear itself (and, in fact, will be linear only if $f$ is a homogeneous quadratic polynomial); it has type $\mathbb{R}^m \to (\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n)$, though the two $\mathbb{R}^m$s have different geometric interpretations: the first is a *point* in $m$-dimensional space, but the second is a *direction*.

The confusion in the single-dimensional case $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ comes from the fact that $A_x$ is also a linear map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is determined only by a single coefficient—it makes no sense to discuss "directional" derivatives when there's only one possible direction. So instead of saying pedantically that the derivative $A_x$ of $f(x) = x^3$ is the map $h \mapsto 3x^2 h$, we'll identify the space of linear maps $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}$ itself, identifying the map $h \mapsto kh$ with $k$, and write $f'(x) = 3x^2$.

Comment: That makes a great deal more sense, thank you! How do we best interpret this variable $h$? As in, using the same example that I gave, the derivative of $f$ at one would be 3, so we have the linear map $h \mapsto 3h$; is there some intuitive explanation as to what this means, particularly in higher dimensions?

Comment: @BillWallis It means the same thing that it does in elementary calculus: it’s a displacement from the point $x$. The only difference is that it’s now a vector quantity in general.

Comment: @BillWallis good question! The intuitive version is that $h$ represents a direction in $\mathbb{R}^m$, and $A(h)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $h$. I've extensively reworked my answer above to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

We are talking about differentiability *at a single point* $x_0$; $A$ is *not* the the function $f'$. The $A$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb R$ and depends on $x_0$. It is a 1x1 matrix, whose single entry is the derivative at that point. If your function is differentiable then at any point $x_0$, this matrix is given by $A_{x_0}=[f'(x_0)]$.

In your example of $f(x)=x^3$, if we're considering differentiabilty at the point 1 for example, the matrix $A$ in the theorem will be $[3]$, and surely you agree that $x\mapsto 3x$ is linear.